# iSpeech SDK for iPhone

Tags: iphone, sdk, speech

I wonder whether iSpeech SDK for iPhone have advertisements when the app is created for production purpose? If so is there any way to disable these ads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what they say on [www.ispeech.org/developers](http://www.ispeech.org/developers)

> We offer our service free of charge for developers; you can create
>   your dream application using our TTS and ASR, without worrying about
>   paying for it.

Get your API and don't worry for paying!

Answer (score 0):

I talked to an ispeech biz dev person who said that you can take out the popup logic. But, in that case, they require "significant cobranding".

We didn't get into the details.

He did say that you don't need a separate key or permission level to disable the popups.